# How to configure node restrictions in Tor Browser 8.5.6 for Android?

Tags: configuration, circuit, android

In Tor Browser for Windows, I can edit the torrc file for things like ExcludeNodes and ExitNodes.  In Orbot for Android, there is a settings menu where these can be configured.

In Tor Browser 8.5.6 for Android, how do I configure these settings?  Is there a torrc file somewhere in the Android file system?  If so, where would I find it?  If not, how do I configure ExcludeNodes and ExitNodes?

Comment: have you found an answer to this ?